# MongoDB unique indexes disallow overwrite

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have created an index with unique=true on one of the fields in my Mongo document.  This works as expected - it disallows duplicates by overwriting the existing entry.

I would like to disallow overwrites, and instead get an error or exception when an attempt is made to insert a duplicate.  Is there any way to do this?  How would I do this with Spring Data MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding WriteConcern=SAFE to the MongoTemplate configuration, I was able to get exceptions when the "unique=true" constraint is violated.  I handle the exception and disallow overwrites.

Answer (score 0):

The indexed annotation has a parameter dropDups=true which would give you what you want.

```
Indexed (unique=true, dropDups=true)
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/Indexed.html

Comment: The dropDups parameter is for the case where you're adding the index on an existing database and you want to drop dups that already exist in the database.  I tried it but it doesn't prevent overwrite.