# Overwriting existing values in unique index field in MongoDB (Aggregating heartbeat events)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, unique-index

I have web page sending heartbeat events to nodejs backend to track how long users are viewing on particular page (or parts of the page). Events are stored to MongoDB in batches using Mongoose's insertMany:

```
Event.insertMany(events)
```

Here `events` is an array containing multiple events. Single event is structured as follows:

```
{user_page_id: 1234, time_spent: 30, ...}
```

Since I'm tracking time spent on page, only most recent `time_spent` value per `user_page_id` is meaningful and I don't want to fill MongoDB with unnecessary data. I tried to deal with this by defining user_page_id as unique index:

```
user_page_id: {type: Number, index: {unique: true, sparse: true}}
```

Now couple questions:

- Is it possible to make `user_site_id` unique so that existing values are always replaced with new values? (Default functionality seems to just reject duplicates. Something was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033272/mongodb-unique-indexes-disallow-overwrite) but didn't help.)
- Is it possible to make `user_site_id` unique so that duplicate `null` values are allowed? (There is also other events where this data is `null`. `sparse` option seems to deal only with missing values)
- Is unique index even possible way to solve this problem or should I find another approach?

Other possible solutions I could think of are:

- Processing heartbeats individually with their own handler using upsert. (Possible but adds some unnecessary(?) complexity to processing pipeline. Also batch mode highly is preferred.)
- Keeping heartbeats in memory and storing them to DB after some timeout. (Problem is that heartbeat timers should be able to pause. Also I would like to keep server stateless.)
- Turning whole thing upside down using websockets. (Possible but adds some unnecessary(?) complexity since sometimes tracking is related to parts of the page and there can be multiple concurrent heartbeat timers on one page.
- Store all events as they are and clean up unnecessary events later with some batch processing job. (Not exactly sure but might cause some performance issues in MongoDB). Also though using capped collection here but doesn't actually solve the problem.

So as a recap the most important question is how to effectively and elegantly deal with aggregation of this sort of heartbeat data?

Comment: Is it just one event per user (the latest) that is of interest or did you mean a few recent events and the rest of it is not useful?

Comment: The most recent since there's no value of storing event that tells user has been on page 60 seconds if we've already stored next event that tells user has been there for 90 seconds